# JavaScript Boolean is not working and looping goes wrong

Tags: javascript, boolean, setinterval, infinite-loop

The demo created is to illustrate the working of the logic described below -

1. I have created 4x4 tiles using JavaScript instead of hard coding into html
2. Code highlight the columns one by one in a infinite loop which is achieved by `setInterval(colScan,1000)`
3. When user press the mouse on html body, it changes the **column scan** --> **row scan** in the **selected column** which is also achieved by `setInterval(rowScan,1000)`
4. When user clicks again on the html body, it changes the **row scan** --> **col scan**

**Problem**:

1. No matter what, colScan is always activated which you can see in the console log that the column is always increasing.
2. When user clicks the second time it doesn't reset to column scan.
3. part of the code where I think the problem is occurring

---

```
createtiles();
var k = 0,
    m = 0,
    selected_col = "",
    mousePressed = false,
    col_scan = true,
    row_scan = false;

scanSelector();

function scanSelector() {
    if (col_scan) {
        setInterval(colScan, 1000);
    } else if (row_scan) {
        setInterval(rowScan, 1000);
    }
}

document.body.onmousedown = function() {
    mousePressed = true;
}

function colScan() {
    if (k > 2) k = 0;
    else k++;
    console.log("col  " + k);
    var col = ".j_" + k;
    $(".tiles").removeClass('highlighter');
    $(col).addClass('highlighter');
    if (mousePressed) {
        mousePressed = false;
        col_scan = false;
        row_scan = true;
        selected_col = col;
        scanSelector();
    }
}

function rowScan() {
    if (m > 2) m = 0;
    else m++;
    console.log("row " + m);
    var row = selected_col + (".i_" + m);
    $(".tiles").removeClass('highlighter');
    $(row).addClass('highlighter');
    if (mousePressed) {
        mousePressed = false;
        col_scan = true;
        row_scan = false;
        selected_col = "";
        scanSelector();
    }
}

function createtiles() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            var divTile = $('<div>', {
                class: 'tiles ' + ("j_" + j) + " " + ("i_" + i)
            });
            divTile.appendTo('.comtile');
        }
    }
}
```

DEMO -> https://codepen.io/xblack/pen/BdGzYx

```js
createtiles();
var k = 0,
  m = 0,
  selected_col = "",
  mousePressed = false,
  col_scan = true,
  row_scan = false;

scanSelector();

function scanSelector() {
  if (col_scan) {
    setInterval(colScan, 1000);
  } else if (row_scan) {
    setInterval(rowScan, 1000);
  }
}

document.body.onmousedown = function() {
  mousePressed = true;
}

function colScan() {
  if (k > 2) k = 0;
  else k++;
  console.log("col  " + k);
  var col = ".j_" + k;
  $(".tiles").removeClass('highlighter');
  $(col).addClass('highlighter');
  if (mousePressed) {
    mousePressed = false;
    col_scan = false;
    row_scan = true;
    selected_col = col;
    scanSelector();
  }
}

function rowScan() {
  if (m > 2) m = 0;
  else m++;
  console.log("row " + m);
  var row = selected_col + (".i_" + m);
  $(".tiles").removeClass('highlighter');
  $(row).addClass('highlighter');
  if (mousePressed) {
    mousePressed = false;
    col_scan = true;
    row_scan = false;
    selected_col = "";
    scanSelector();
  }
}

function createtiles() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      var divTile = $('<div>', {
        class: 'tiles ' + ("j_" + j) + " " + ("i_" + i)
      });
      divTile.appendTo('.comtile');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box!important;
}

.conatiner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-area: "menu" "comContent";
}

.menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  height: 5vh;
  padding: 2vh;
}

.comtile {
  grid-area: comContent;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 0.5vh;
  height: 95vh;
  padding: 2vh;
}

.tiles {
  background: #F7F7F7;
  border-radius: 0.4vh;
  border: 1px solid #EEEBEB;
}

.highlighter {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.38, -0.76, 0, 1.69);
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">MAIN MENU</div>
  <div class="comtile"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: dont see a single `clearInterval`.

Comment: why do I need clearInterval? can you please explain?

Comment: `setInterval` calls your function regularly. If you call it again, the function from the second call to `setInterval` is just called regularly **as well**

Comment: @ASDFGerte where should I use clearInterval? I am new to creating infinite loop in JavaScript .. thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the following changes:

Replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout` for reasons stated by @ASDFGerte.

```
function scanSelector() {
    if (col_scan) {
        // Replace setInterval with setTimeout
        setTimeout(colScan, 1000);
    } else i f (row_scan) {
        // Replace setInterval with setTimeout
        setTimeout(rowScan, 1000);
    }
}
```

Move the `scanSelector()` lines in `rowScan` and `colScan`. The change is the same for both methods, I will only show the change in `rowScan`.

```
function rowScan() {
    if (m > 2) m = 0;
    else m++;
    console.log("row " + m);
    var row = selected_col + (".i_" + m);
    $(".tiles").removeClass('highlighter');
    $(row).addClass('highlighter');
    if (mousePressed) {
        mousePressed = false;
        col_scan = true;
        row_scan = false;
        selected_col = "";
        // Remove this line
        // scanSelector();
    }
    // Because you're no longer using setInterval you need to call 
    // this method after each timeout.
    scanSelector();
}
```

Every time you were calling `scanSelector()` it would create another interval. The initial interval will highlight the columns, after the first click you have two intervals running side-by-side: the original interval and an interval to highlight rows. After each click you're only adding intervals.

You could store the interval ID, the result of `setInterval` and clear this interval when you change from column to row highlight and vice versa. The easier solution is moving from `setInterval` to `setTimeout` as outlined in the changed I've shown you above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) It is working now. I am new to this and I didn't know the proper usage. thanks again. Can I ask why down vote my question? It was pretty straight forward problem. Till now I was thinking it was my logic problem but it turned out that I didn't know the proper usage of the setInterval :(

Comment: I didn't vote down your question. Your question is better formulated than most questions and it has working code. Perhaps someone else can explain the down vote.

Comment: For future reference: when writing JS and you're using a method you don't know that well, check MDN. For instance this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers would've helped you a lot. It is a great resource when you're a web developer.